# How to match a column value of one dataframe with lookup table and set values with an offset cumsum?

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension, vlookup

I have the following dataframes:

```py
# Creating Data_One_df
data_one = {
    "Date": ["12/1/2022"] * 7,
    "Time": ["6:30", "6:35", "6:40", "6:45", "6:50", "6:55", "7:00"],
    "Bars_left": [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
    "6:30": [""] * 7,
    "6:35": [""] * 7,
    "6:40": [""] * 7,
    "6:45": [""] * 7,
    "6:50": [""] * 7,
    "6:55": [""] * 7,
    "7:00": [""] * 7,
}
Data_One_df = pd.DataFrame(data_one)

# Creating Data_Two_df
data_two = {
    "Time": ["6:30", "6:35", "6:40", "6:45", "6:50", "6:55", "7:00"],
    "Fcst": [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1],
}
Data_Two_df = pd.DataFrame(data_two)
```

I want to populate columns of `Data_One_df` (input table) by matching the row value of the 'Time' column to the 'Time' column in `Data_Two_df` (lookup table) and returning the offset (1 row down) of the cumsum of the 'Fcst' to the offset (1 column to the right) of the 'Input table'.

For example: for row 6:30 in `Data_One_df`, I want to find the corresponding row in `Data_Two_df` ('lookup table') (i.e. 6:30) and then offset (i.e. 6:35). Next, calculate the cumsum starting at 6:35, which is 8. Place that result in the column (6:35) of 'input table'. I then want to repeat this value across all columns.

Here is what the expected result should look like:

```py
data_three = {
    "Date": ["12/1/2022"] * 7,
    "Time": ["6:30", "6:35", "6:40", "6:45", "6:50", "6:55", "7:00"],
    "Bars_left": [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
    "6:30": ["NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN"],
    "6:35": [8, "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN"],
    "6:40": [8, 6, "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN"],
    "6:45": [8, 6, 5, "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN"],
    "6:50": [8, 6, 5, 4, "NaN", "NaN", "NaN"],
    "6:55": [8, 6, 5, 4, 2, "NaN", "NaN"],
    "7:00": [8, 6, 5, 4, 2, 1, "NaN"],
}
Desired_df = pd.DataFrame(data_three)
```

[image: Output Dataframes]

I tried numerous methods, to no avail. The latest code effort is the following:

```py
# Get a list of time columns
time_cols = Data_One_df.columns[3:]

# Loop through the time columns and update the values
# in Data_One_df based on Data_Two_df
for i, col in enumerate(time_cols):
    # Get the corresponding forecast value from Data_Two_df
    fcst = Data_Two_df["Fcst"][i]
    # Update the values in Data_One_df based on the forecast
    Data_One_df[col] = [np.nan] * fcst + list(Data_One_df[col][fcst:])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it with Pandas [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and [cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```py
# Add necessary infos to Data_Two_df
Data_Two_df["Left_Time"] = Data_Two_df["Time"].shift(-1)
Data_Two_df["Fcst_cumsum"] = Data_Two_df["Fcst"][::-1].cumsum()[::-1].shift(-1)
Data_Two_df = Data_Two_df.dropna()

# Add values to Data_One_df
Data_One_df = Data_One_df.replace("", pd.NA)
for t, left_t, val in zip(
    Data_Two_df["Time"], Data_Two_df["Left_Time"], Data_Two_df["Fcst_cumsum"]
):
    Data_One_df.loc[Data_One_df["Time"] == t, left_t] = val
Data_One_df.loc[:, "6:30":] = Data_One_df.loc[:, "6:30":].fillna(method="ffill", axis=1)
```

Then:

```py
print(Data_One_df)
# Output
        Date  Time  Bars_left  6:30  6:35  6:40  6:45  6:50  6:55  7:00
0  12/1/2022  6:30          6  <NA>   8.0   8.0   8.0   8.0   8.0   8.0
1  12/1/2022  6:35          5  <NA>  <NA>   6.0   6.0   6.0   6.0   6.0
2  12/1/2022  6:40          4  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   5.0   5.0   5.0   5.0
3  12/1/2022  6:45          3  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   4.0   4.0   4.0
4  12/1/2022  6:50          2  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   2.0   2.0
5  12/1/2022  6:55          1  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   1.0
6  12/1/2022  7:00          0  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```